# How to create plot with multiple labels on X axis, previous code suggestion doesn't seem to work

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid, gtable

I have some data measuring rate of dislodgement for a species with three different variables (exposure, season and site). I would like to create a plot where Season and exposure are listed on the X axis and site is created in a legend. I have completed this easily enough in Excel, and would like to replicate the same type in R. At the moment, I'm using a piece of code which seemed to work for another user with a similar question on, but this doesnt seem to work with mine?

SCRIPT:

```
dput(Data2)
structure(list(Season = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("Autumn", "Spring", "Summer ", "Winter"), class = "factor"), 
Exposure = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c(" Sheltered", "Exposed", "Moderately Exposed", 
"Sheltered"), class = "factor"), Average = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), Site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), SEM = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))


`setwd("C:/Users/phl5/Documents/PippaPhD")
 getwd()
 read.csv("Graphed_Data.csv")
 Data2<-read.csv("Graphed_Data.csv")

 library(ggplot2)
 library(gtable)
 library(grid)

 dodge<- position_dodge(width=0.9)

 ggplot(Data2, aes(x = interaction(Exposure, Season), y = Average, fill 
  = factor(Site))) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Average + SEM, ymin = Average - SEM), position 
 = dodge, width = 0.2)


 g1<- ggplot(data = Data2, aes(x = interaction(Exposure, Season), y = 
 Average, fill = factor(Site))) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Average + SEM, ymin = Average - SEM), position 
 = dodge, width = 0.2) +
 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 12.5))+ 
 annotate("text", x = 1:12, y = 400,
       label = rep(c("Exposed", "Moderately Exposed", "Sheltered"),4)) +
 annotate("text", c(0.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5), y = -800, label = c("Spring", 
 "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter"))+
 theme_classic()+
 theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "lines"),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank())

 g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
 g2$layout$clip[g2$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
 grid.draw(g2)`
```

Can anyone see if the is an obvious problem in my code that I'm using or if the is a different script that I could use?

Code: 
[Output get from current code, with the problem of no x axis codes appearing at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfYRD.png)

[This is the kind of output I would want, and that I can create in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXBFm.png)

I'm very much a beginner in R, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

For the OP's second question in the comment:

1. There is no need to add a `geom_hline()` to display the axis, just add `axis.line` to the `theme()` and `panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines")` to make it continuous across facets

```
gg <- ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Site), y=Average, fill=as.factor(Site)), data=data)
gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
gg <- gg + scale_fill_discrete(guide_legend(title = 'Site')) # just to get 'site' instead of 'as.factor(Site)' as legend title
# gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values=c('black', 'grey85'), guide_legend(title = 'Site')) # to get bars in black and grey instead of ggplot's default colors
# gg <- gg + theme_classic() # get white background and black axis.line for x- and y-axis
gg <- gg + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average-SEM, ymax=Average+SEM), width=.3)
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Season*Exposure, strip.position=c('bottom'), nrow=1, drop=F)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .05))) # remove space below zero
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.line = element_line(color='black'),
                 strip.placement = 'outside', # place x-axis above (factor-label-) strips
                 panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines"), # remove space between facets (for continuous x-axis)
                 panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), # remove vertical grid lines
                 # panel.grid = element_blank(), # remove all grid lines
                 # panel.background = element_rect(fill='white'), # choose background color for plot area
                 strip.background = element_rect(fill='white', color='white')  # choose background for factor labels, color just matters for theme_classic()
)
```

2. To place exposure labels above season labels in the facet strips you can change the gtable overlayed on each strip

```
# facet factor levels
season.levels <- levels(data$Season)
exposure.levels <- levels(data$Exposure)

# convert to gtable
g <- ggplotGrob(gg)

# find the grobs of the strips in the original plot
grob.numbers <- grep("strip-b", g$layout$name)
# filter strips from layout 
b.strips <- gtable_filter(g, "strip-b", trim = FALSE)
# b.strips$layout shows the strips position in the cell grid of the plot
# b.strips$layout
season.left.panels <- seq(1, by=length(levels(data$Exposure)), length.out = length(season.levels))
season.right.panels <- seq(length(exposure.levels), by=length(exposure.levels), length.out = length(season.levels))
left <- b.strips$layout$l[season.left.panels]
right <- b.strips$layout$r[season.right.panels]
top <- b.strips$layout$t[1]
bottom <- b.strips$layout$b[1]

# create empty matrix as basis to overly new gtable on the strip
mat   <- matrix(vector("list", length = 10), nrow = 2)
mat[] <- list(zeroGrob())

# add new gtable matrix above each strip
for (i in 1:length(season.levels)) {
  res <- gtable_matrix("season.strip", mat, unit(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), "null"), unit(c(1, 1), "null"))
  season.left <- season.left.panels[i]
  # place season labels below exposure labels in row 2 of the overlayed gtable for strips
  res <- gtable_add_grob(res, g$grobs[[grob.numbers[season.left]]]$grobs[[1]], 2, 1, 2, 5)
  # move exposure labels to row 1 of the overlayed gtable for strips
  for (j in 0:2) {
    exposure.x <- season.left+j
    res$grobs[[c(1, 5, 9)[j+1]]] <- g$grobs[[grob.numbers[exposure.x]]]$grobs[[2]]
  }
  new.grob.name <- paste0(levels(data$Season)[i], '-strip')
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g, res, t = top,  l = left[i],  b = top,  r = right[i], name = c(new.grob.name))
  new.grob.no <- grep(new.grob.name, g$layout$name)[1]
  g$grobs[[new.grob.no]]$grobs[[nrow(g$grobs[[new.grob.no]]$layout)]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$gp <- gpar(fontface='bold')
}

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

3. To also get the bars in black and grey as in your example picture change the ggplot like this:

```
gg <- ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Site), y=Average, fill=as.factor(Site)), data=data)
gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
# gg <- gg + scale_fill_discrete(guide_legend(title = 'Site')) # just to get 'site' instead of 'as.factor(Site)' as legend title
gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values=c('black', 'grey85'), guide_legend(title = 'Site')) # to get bars in black and grey instead of ggplot's default colors
gg <- gg + theme_classic() # get white background and black axis.line for x- and y-axis
gg <- gg + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average-SEM, ymax=Average+SEM), width=.3)
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Season*Exposure, strip.position=c('bottom'), nrow=1, drop=F)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .05))) # remove space below zero
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.line = element_line(color='black'),
                 strip.placement = 'outside', # place x-axis above (factor-label-) strips
                 panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines"), # remove space between facets (for continuous x-axis)
                 panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), # remove vertical grid lines
                 # panel.grid = element_blank(), # remove all grid lines
                 # panel.background = element_rect(fill='white'), # choose background color for plot area
                 strip.background = element_rect(fill='white', color='white')  # choose background for factor labels, color just matters for theme_classic()
)
```

The result should look like this:
[image]
**Edit:**

For the OP's question in the comment:

1. Removing grid lines can be done using `ggplot`'s `theme()`:

```
gg <- ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Site), y=Average, fill=as.factor(Site)), data=data)
gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
gg <- gg + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average-SEM, ymax=Average+SEM), width=.3)
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Season*Exposure, strip.position=c('bottom'), nrow=1, drop=F)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_discrete(guide_legend(title = 'Site'))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), # remove vertical grid lines
                 # panel.grid = element_blank(), # remove al grid lines
                 # panel.background = element_rect(fill='white'), # choose background color for plot area
                 strip.background = element_rect(fill='white')  # choose background for factor labels
                 )
```

2. To have only one label for each season is a bit more tricky. You'll need to edit the `gtable` of the `ggplot`.
   One way to do so would be this:

```
# facet factor levels
season.levels <- levels(data$Season)
exposure.levels <- levels(data$Exposure)
# convert to gtable
g <- ggplotGrob(gg)
# find the grobs of the strips in the original plot
grob.numbers <- grep("strip-b", g$layout$name)
# filter strips from layout 
b.strips <- gtable_filter(g, "strip-b", trim = FALSE)
# b.strips$layout shows the strips position in the cell grid of the plot
b.strips$layout
season.left.panels <- seq(1, by=length(levels(data$Exposure)), length.out = length(season.levels))
season.right.panels <- seq(length(exposure.levels), by=length(exposure.levels), length.out = length(season.levels))
left <- b.strips$layout$l[season.left.panels]
right <- b.strips$layout$r[season.right.panels]
top <- b.strips$layout$t[1]
bottom <- b.strips$layout$b[1]

# create empty matrix as basis to overly new gtable on the strip
mat   <- matrix(vector("list", length = 10), nrow = 2)
mat[] <- list(zeroGrob())

# add new gtable matrix above each strip
for (i in 1:length(season.levels)) {
  res <- gtable_matrix("season.strip", mat, unit(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), "null"), unit(c(1, 1), "null"))
  res <- gtable_add_grob(res, g$grobs[[grob.numbers[season.left.panels[i]]]]$grobs[[1]], 1, 1, 1, 5)
  new.grob.name <- paste0(levels(data$Season)[i], '-strip')
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g, res, t = top,  l = left[i],  b = top,  r = right[i], name = c(new.grob.name))
  new.grob.no <- grep(new.grob.name, g$layout$name)
  g$grobs[[new.grob.no]]$grobs[[nrow(g$grobs[[new.grob.no]]$layout)]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$gp <- gpar(fontface='bold')
}
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

**Original answer**

I think what you are looking for can – using `ggplot()` – be best achieved using facetting.

```
data <- expand.grid(c('Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter'), c('Sheltered', 'Moderately exposed', 'Exposed'), c(1, 2))
names(data) <- c('Season', 'Exposure', 'Site')
# adding some arbitrary values
set.seed(42)
data$Average <- sample(c(rep(3, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(1, 2), rep(NA, 17)))
data$SEM <- NA
SEM <- sample(c(rep(0.5, 3), rep(0.3, 2), rep(.1, 2)))
data$SEM[which(!is.na(data$Average))] <- SEM

gg <- ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Site), y=Average, fill=as.factor(Site)), data=data)
gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
gg <- gg + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average-SEM, ymax=Average+SEM), width=.3)
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Season*Exposure, strip.position=c('bottom'), nrow=1, drop=F)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_discrete(guide_legend(title = 'Site'))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.title.x = element_blank())
print(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice NSUser. This is the kind of thing I was hoping to achieve. Is the a way to make the background pure white instead of gridded and with axis lines? Also would it be possible to only have one label stating the Season, instead of the three repetitions? Possibly leave the middle label in, out of the three so it is nicely centered?

Comment: This is great thank you! I've removed the extra spacing around the x axis and added a y axis line. But I'm struggling to add a black line for the x axis. I've used the code 'geom_hline(yintercept=0")' but this gives a dashed black line with space between the labels and only appears if I take out the code to remove the excess spacing around the x axis.Is the a way around this, which would give a continuous line without leaving space around the X axis? Finally, is it simple to switch over the x axis labels, with the exposure labels first/directly below the bars, and then the season?

Comment: Thanks for the code it was exactly what i wanted. I've got another question based on this code but thought it easier to create a new question rather than continuously comment,  I'd be very grateful if you would be able to suggest anything? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836092/how-to-customize-the-x-axis-of-two-factors-and-colour-bars-based-on-two-factors

Answer (score 1):

since you did not provide sample data to go along with your code, I am trying to figure out your problem with pre-exisiting data (`cars`).
After looking at your desired output, I created a barplot in `r`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x =  speed, y = dist)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Your code has the problem of manually overriding the x-axis to be blank, like so:

```
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x =  speed, y = dist)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend = F, position = "dodge") + 
  theme(
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

As you see, the x-axis and their labels disappear when you control `axis.title` / `axis.text`

[image]